# Multithreaded matrix addition taking longer than single threaded version in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

Getting my hands dirty with concurrency in Java and ran into this rather common issue with multithreading. I have a piece of code (as follows) which simply takes two matrices, m1 and m2, and writes the sum of `m1[i][j]` and `m2[i][j]` to `result[i][j]`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < numCols ; i++) {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < numRows ; j++) {
                int finalI = i;
                int finalJ = j;
                executorService.execute(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run()  {
                                    ArrayList<Integer> v1 = m1.get(finalI);
                                    Integer m1Val = v1.get(finalJ);
                                    ArrayList<Integer> v2 = m2.get(finalI);
                                    Integer m2Val = v2.get(finalJ);
                                    result.get(finalI).add(finalJ,  m1Val + m2Val);
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        }
```

the arrays are of type `ArrayLists<ArrayList<Integer>>` where each nested `ArrayList` describes a column. They are of dimensions `numRows` x `numCols`. I measured the timing of this operation to sum a pair of randomly generated matrices of size 10000 x 10000, and found that the single-threaded version took me 123s and the multi-threaded (11 threads on 6-Core intel i7) version took me around 300s.

I chose to use ArrayList in this case as they allow for unsafe concurrent access, i.e I can modify different parts of the ArrayList simultaneously. However, this hasn't provided any additional speedup that I would have expected. My guess as to why I don't see a speedup is because of the following:

1. The memory bus gets jammed up so it cannot handle multiple reads/writes to RAM being done by the threads, so the memory speed is a bottleneck.
2. I used a Executors.newFixedThreadPool for this operation. After each read from the RAM, the L1 cache is updated to improve data access speed. However, this cache is invalidated as the next task performed on a thread on a given processor might require data at a different location in memory which might not be cached at L1 or L2 levels, thus increasing timing.

Do these guesses make sense? Any additional explanation I might not seeing?

Comment: The guesses make sense to me. All parallelism creates context switching as you have to manage N number of parallel contexts and switch accordingly and also over parallelism can create artificial bottlenecks where a resource may suffer to have to balance multiple consumers needs above what it can supply at a reasonable rate.

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with Java concurrency, but aren't you creating a distinct runnable for every element in the matrix, which would cause a significant slowdown? I tried this now, using an ExecutorService (11 threads) and creating a new task per row of 10,000 elements, and it takes ~15-20 seconds (had some solutions that were ~5-10 seconds but contained issues with concurrent modification that I'm not interested in debugging). Using the parallel Stream API took ~25-30 seconds. I'm not certain I took the optimal approach in either case but it's significantly better than your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 main issues:

1. You are scheduling a runnable for every single addition that you perform as part of the matrix addition. There is a tremendous overhead from creating the Runnable, putting it on a thread-safe queue (as used internally by the threadpool), and having the worker threads polling that queue for tasks.
2. You are using a very inefficient data structure for the matrix (`ArrayLists<ArrayList<Integer>>`) with poor data locality and a large overhead for accessing individual items.

Both 1 and 2 result in many extra CPU cycles that are completely wasted; they also both result in poor data-locality in more than necessary cache misses.

In addition, you're getting incorrect results because you are using a non-thread-safe data structure ("ArrayList in this case as they allow for unsafe concurrent access") to collect the results; it it wasn't pre-populated with `Integer` values for every result, then you will lose data as the list expands and overwrites earlier data.

An efficient approach would be:

1. Put as many threads in the threadpool as you have CPU cores. Give each thread a section of the matrix, and let every `Runnable` perform addition on that entire section. That means, if you have 8 cores, and 8 worker threads, then each thread will handle one Runnable, and that Runnable performs addition on 12.5% of your matrix.
2. Use an `int[][]` for your data structure, or even better, use an `int[]` and do your own calculation for the index of `row * width + col`. This provides much better data locality, and doesn't do any auto-boxing and unboxing, resulting in higher speed as well. Using `int[]` is particularly good for adding matrices, as you can just treat the matrix as an array - you don't need to know about rows and columns, just `result[i] = m1[i] + m2[i];`

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestions resulted in a noticeable speedup. For each of the matrices containing exactly 1 billion integers, the time taken on a single thread was 7346ms, whereas it was 1567ms on 12 threads.